# Align div elements with html elements next to each other and under each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having some issue's to get my div's aligned next to each other aswell as under each other.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwm10nhn/7/

[image]

**My Css rules:**

```
.wrap{
}

.wrappedLabel{
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.wrappedControl{
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.wrappedElement{
float: left;
}
```

**What I want as result is the following:**

[image]

I archieved this by adding `clear:left` to the first element next to the select. In this example this is the `div.wrappedElement` which contains the FirstName However the html is generated in code. Is their a simple way to do this in CSS ?

Thanks.

Comment: your code in jsfiddle it not readable, its like one big mess

Comment: @VDesign should be formatted now.

Answer (score 1):

add a parent div and add this css

```
.seperate{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/vwm10nhn/5/

Comment: Problem is my html is generated so the controls dont have a fixed position. It can be random so that for example the select control is first on the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try for putting under each other:

```
.wrappedElement{
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}
```